# listview in drawer not clicking

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

Im trying to have a navigationdrawer witouth title or drawer bar, mostly like google maps drawer, the problem is that the listview in drawer doesnt click I have like 5 items but no one is clickable,

here is the layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:focusable="false" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainScreen" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/map"
        android:scaleType="matrix" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >
        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
            android:layout_width="301dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/actv" >
        </AutoCompleteTextView>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_myplaces" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mylocation" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

please any help is apreciated.

Comment: Does your imageview or imagebutton take focus when you click on list item??

Comment: I actually just changed now the layout, I removed the RelativeLayout and put all what was inside into the Framelayout, and now I can click on the laistview in the drawer, the issue is without its not designable with the RelativeLayout!! do you suggest me somenthing like the relative view that would work under the Framelayout.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

replaceFragment(R.id.view_main,new HomeFragment(), false);
replaceFragment(R.id.left_drawer, new LeftMenuFragment(), false);

Each frame worked independently.
call the relative layout and the list in the left frame